# Need some help with JavaScript variables in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript

Can you say why this code doesn't work for me?
SharePoint 2010. I have no ideas any more about how to set this value to global object :(

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
var context = null;
var web = null;
var currentUser = null;
var currentUserData = {
"userLogin": "templogin"
};

function getWebUserData() {
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    currentUser.retrieve();
    context.load(web);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), 
         Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
};

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
    var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
    alert('User name:' + userObject.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + 
             userObject.get_loginName());
    // export loginName value into global object
    currentUserData.userLogin = userObject.get_loginName();
};

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
};

// output (alert) value from global obj properties.
// it doesn's work.
alert("Once more time: \n Current User Login: " + currentUserData.userLogin);
```

Comment: Are you getting null in the alert box? I think its because the value is not initialized.

Comment: declare the variables before calling ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");

Comment: Hello!
I have a "templogin" in alert message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the asynchronous behaviour of JavaScript Client Object model. The statement `alert("Once more time: \n Current User Login: " + currentUserData.userLogin);` is executed immediately after `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");` It does not wait for success handler to finish.
If you put alert after `currentUserData.userLogin = userObject.get_loginName();` it should work. However, if your need is to use it outside, then you may use JavaScript callbacks or JQuery Defrreds/Promises. 
See this for more information:
http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-using-deferredspromises-or.html

Comment: Thank you, Nadeem! Very useful post! I'll try to play with callbacks today.